# Add icon to Laravelcollective submit button

Tags: html, css, laravel, laravel-5, laravelcollective

I'm trying to add a trash icon to submit button and I tried this :

```
{!! Form::submit('', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-sm fa fa-trash']) !!}
```

but the icon won't show. How to solve this ? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try to use Form::button instead of Form::submit:

```
{{ Form::button('<i class="fa fa-trash"></i>', ['type' => 'submit', 'class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-sm'] )  }}
```

Comment: Yes <input> do not support pseudo element (:before, :after). and Font awesome works on :after

Comment: If it "works flawlessly", then mark it as the solution please, so the others know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try too with:

**Example to input type button:**

```
{{ FORM::button('<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i> Text button',['class'=>'button button-red','type'=>'button','id'=>'id-button']) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

there are not possible try it
laravel collective form given very competition

```
<button class='btn btn-primary' type='submit' value='submit'>
<i class='fa fa-save'> </i> Save
```